# trocar o valor do atributo com jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho o seguinte **js**:

```
  $("a.bloqDesbloq").click(function() {

         $.post ("../_requeridos/alteraAdministrador.php", {

             idAdministrador   : $(this).attr('idAdmin'),
             bloq              : $(this).attr('bloq')

         }, function(_retorno){

              retorno = JSON.parse(_retorno);


              if (retorno[1] == "OK") {

                  url      = $("a[idAdmin='" + retorno[3] + "']").find('img')
                  bloqueio = $("a[idAdmin='" + retorno[3] + "']")

                  if (retorno[2] == "s")  
                      url.prop("src",'_img/desbloquear.png'),
                      bloqueio.prop('bloq','n')

                  if (retorno[2] == "n")  
                      url.prop("src",'_img/bloquear.png'),
                      bloqueio.prop('bloq','s')

                  //location.reload();

              } else {

                  alert("Erro no bloqueio");

              }

           }
          );

          return false;

  });
```

Essa parte do código,

```
          if (retorno[1] == "OK") {

              url      = $("a[idAdmin='" + retorno[3] + "']").find('img')
              bloqueio = $("a[idAdmin='" + retorno[3] + "']")

              if (retorno[2] == "s")  
                  url.prop("src",'_img/desbloquear.png'),
                  bloqueio.prop('bloq','n')
              if (retorno[2] == "n")  
                  url.prop("src",'_img/bloquear.png'),
                  bloqueio.prop('bloq','s')

              //location.reload();

          }
```

Tem por objetivo alterar 2 coisas:

A) A **imagem** do **link**

B) Um **atributo** chamado **bloq** que recebe 2 valores possíveis `'s'` ou `'n'`;

A **imagem** está trocando corretamente. Mas o **atributo** **bloq** não está.

Onde estou errando?

Eis o HTML

```
<a class='bloqDesbloq' idAdmin=<?php echo $administrador->getIdAdmin(); ?> bloq='s'>
   <?php echo $imagem; ?>
</a>
```

Que muda conforme a leitura no banco

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente usar attr em vez de prop:

```
url.attr("src",'_img/desbloquear.png'),
bloqueio.attr('bloq','n')
```

Comment: Exatamente isso. Deu certo! attr para o HTML prop está só no DOM